# How to set select value using Reactive form and looping through array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to set select value dynamically but the changes are not reflected even with using detect changes.

Component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }
  genders=['male','female'];
  SignupForm:FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
      'gender':new FormControl(),
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.SignupForm);
  }

  setGender() {
    this.SignupForm.controls.gender.setValue(this.genders[1]);
    console.log(this.SignupForm.controls.gender.value);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1">
            <form [formGroup]="SignupForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <select fromControlName="gender">
         <option *ngFor="let g of genders">{{g}}</option>
       </select>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button> 
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setGender()">Set Female</button>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-ryypmv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very little error, see:

```
<select fromControlName="gender">
```

Change by:

```
<select formControlName="gender">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try something looking like the following, this would be selecting a default option for the `select / option` by getting it to read the value of the form control which would be set early into the lifecycle of the component.

**Solution**

Add this to your options to set the default the the form value.

```
<option *ngFor="let g of genders" [selected]="gender.value">{{g}}</option>
```

Then within your component.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
  'gender':new FormControl(),
 });
}

public setGender(): void
{
     this.gender.setValue(this.genders[1]);
     this.cd.detectChanges();
     console.log(this.gender) // just check here the value is set correct.  
}

public get gender(): AbstractControl
{
    return this.SignupForm.controls['gender']
}
```

This should give the the required functionality. Looking a little neater. 
Here is an [article](https://medium.com/@kastepanyan24/how-to-set-selected-option-dynamically-in-angular-6-85c99958cca5)
someone wrote on the subject. All the best.